# using globals in channel entry tag

Tags: channel-entries, channel, variable

so I am trying to use a dynamic variable, this works

```
{member_id}   
{exp:channel:entries channel="vacancies" author_id="9"}
```

and this does not

```
 {member_id}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="vacancies" author_id="{member_id}"}
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Mo'Variables http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables then you could use:

> "Early-parsed Member Variables (for use as tag paramters):
>   {logged_in_member_id}, {logged_in_group_id}, {logged_in_username},
>   {logged_in_screen_name}, {logged_in_email}"

Hope it helps

Comment: brilliant thanks, also got a few other variables I can use that will come in pretty handy - {rev_segment_1} looks great.

Comment: Yeah, it has plenty other functions that can be useful if needed.